# ipPython input error, it starts with \x1b[4;710;528t. Is color the problem?

Tags: python, input, colors, valueerror

My program isn't simple, but I have a simple problem...
I want to do an input, but there's colors in my script ( I use python 3 ), and when I try to input a value the value starts with something like : \x1b[4;710;528t1. This is my code :

```
print("Your {Y}IP{R} is{Y}".format(Y=YELLOW, R=RED), ipv4,"{R}.{N}".format(R=RED, N=NORMAL))
ip=input("NUMBER > {B}".format(B=BASIC))
ip=int(a)
```

And of course at the beginning I put:

```
RED = "\033[1;31m"  
BLUE = "\033[1;34m"
CYAN = "\033[1;36m"
GREEN = "\033[1;32m"
YELLOW = "\33[1;93m"
NORMAL = "\033[1;37m"
BASIC = "\033[0;0m"
```

And I don't know why this isn't working, it worked fine without colors but I need to add some.
When I convert a to int I have exactly the following error :

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x1b[4;710;528tx'
```

Where the last x is the value I put in the input.
I didn't find anything on Internet... Can someone help please ? Thanks
The traceback is:

```
  File "main.py", line 41, in <module>
    ip=int(ip)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x1b[4;710;528t165'
```

Comment: Couldn't replicate, works find for me. Are you sure it's these lines throwing the error? Can you post your full traceback?

Comment: Thanks to answer so fast ! The Traceback is :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 41, in <module>
    ip=int(ip)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x1b[4;710;528t165'

Comment: please include the traceback in the question and not in comments. Anyway, the line `ip=int(ip)` is giving you the error, not the lines you posted in your question

Comment: Yes I changed the name of this variable when I posted it